# Allow room owners to suspend users from a chat room

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, chat

I realise that the chat system is somewhat "removed" from the network and almost "subsidiary" to it - but I feel it's a very important part of the network and contributes back to the ethos that SE stands for.

Thankfully, it happens rarely, but RO's should be able to ban/suspend users from their own rooms without having to flag and require moderator intervention.

All the "big/popular" rooms have established SO members as RO's - maybe we can (as it were) tilt the board a bit so that we don't have to bother moderators?

**Suggested amendment keeping faith with @Ffisegydd's comment**

- Allow ROs to *suspend* a user from a room
- Upon doing so, the system should automatically count that as a flag for mod attention
- Upon doing so, the system should automatically raise a *leave* event for that user for that room
- The time could be limited to something less than 4 hours?

From my perspective this'd allow rooms to "look after themselves" a bit better - it'd also with the auto-raising a flag allow suspension and notice of offensive avatars joining that haven't spoken/haven't performed any action on the site to flag otherwise be "gone".

Instead of "trash-canning" messages and flagging for mod intervention, this proposal puts it somewhat the other way around. Allow ROs to "immediately suspend" a user, while at the same time auto-raising a flag that a mod can consider (at some point in the next 4 hours or something...). From my POV - it buys everyone some time.

Comment: If this were to be implemented I would prefer it to be a "limited suspension" rather than a "ban". My idea of it is that ROs could suspend someone for N hours which effectively removes their write-access to the chatroom. If someone is suspended repeatedly then a moderator is automatically flagged as it obviously points to some greater issue.

Comment: What is also interesting with the automatic flag approach is that an abusive RO would be spotted relatively soon as well.

Comment: This does leave room for a large amount of "power-tripping", but as @MatthieuM. stated, the moderators could pick up on abusive RO's if that were the case.

Comment: hmm, I will now be suspended even more... but good case, +1

Comment: This probably belongs on [Meta.SE].

Comment: @minitech can you mark this as completed? It's been done systemwide now for a few weeks/months via the kickmute system.

Comment: @Benjamin good catch... I'd completely forgotten about this post :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the sake of completion, this feature has been implemented and rolled out to all the chat rooms now. It is called as `kick-mute`. Overview of this feature can be found in this [`balpha`'s answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239226/235416).

Answer (score 18):

As a room owner myself and the recent star-spam fiasco in the JavaScript, I support this notion.

There would of course need to be checks and balances to ensure that room owners don't get ban happy.