# Please ban those users

Tags: support, status-completed, new-users, offensive

I just found the following users in our chat (and other):

- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4010560/user4010560
- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4010573/user4010573
- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4010549/user4010549
- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4010592/user4010592
- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4010619/user4010619
- https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4010645/pissed-off-of-this-bullshit

Please delete it. That is nazi stuff which I personally don't tolerate.

Comment: Don't stress about it. The mods/devs are on the case and well aware of it and dealing with it as appropriate... Just reload your chat tab occasionally while the team destroy the accounts.

Comment: I reloaded it they are still there

Comment: They won't be for long... just be a little patient while the team sorts it out... it's been going on for a good 10 hours or so now... it's a known troller and is being addressed... don't think there's much more to say apart from that

Comment: Okay I see I saw that the first time. Is there another question which collects such profiles?

Comment: To the mods: How do we flag such user if he has no questions / answers?

Comment: And can we get an option to ban users from a chat

Comment: It appears that the parent accounts for those chat users have been destroyed, so this is probably just a caching issue.

Comment: @Patrick Flag one of your own posts with the 'other' reason.

Comment: @Emrakul: I know, but usually you would flag this as offensive, which goes a lot faster through the queue that the other flags.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I made a proposal a while back: [Allow room owners to suspend users from a chat room](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262825/allow-room-owners-to-suspend-users-from-a-chat-room) - that would address such things...

Comment: @JonClements: I was more talking about the main site. Personally I am not very active in chat.

Comment: Why are some of the accounts in discussion still displaying fascist symbols that are [threatened by criminal prosecution in some countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika#Post-WWII_stigmatization)?

Comment: @syck I agree with you that the chat users should been deleted too. But that parent accounts are deleted.

Comment: Would it be the same if the profiles would show nudeness or some other offensive content? After all those profiles are still google- and findable, at least through rekire's links.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

We're working on cleaning this up, and putting some things in place that doesn't make it so easy to just 'decorate the room list with hate' as they have been.

These people are the lowest of the low, and we're quite close to not having to deal with their s^&@ for very much longer.

Please, bear with us.

Comment: Thank you for addressing this seriously :) I can't wait for a clean chat again. The troll in question thinks his "hacking" skills are too much for y'all. I'd love to see y'all throw that in his face. :D

Comment: Why are the chat profiles not deleted? Some of the links above still show that original avatars...