# A user lost the username in the chat room

Tags: support, chat

The conversation in comments under [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078651/malloc-in-a-loop-using-valgrind) question got a tad too lengthy, and was moved to a chat. Curiously, the OP has lost their name in the chat room (displayed as just "user9807...", see screenshot below). In the question, the name displayed is "Jamin". [Chat user](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/9807992) doesn't seem to have inherited the parent user's name. Is this intended?

[image: The user has lost the username]

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Users with less than 20 reputation have a generic icon and username in chat. This is intentional to prevent abusive/rude names or avatars (there were a few [incidents](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270689/please-ban-those-users)).

From the [chat FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#avatar)

> If you are a new user with very little reputation, then instead of the avatar you usually have on Stack Overflow you may see the non-descript shape shown on the left and a default display name. Because we have had issues with offensive avatars and user names in the past, we hide new users' avatars and names in chat until they have earned some reputation on Stack Overflow.

Comment: For context: [Please ban those users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270689/please-ban-those-users)

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/18698839#18698839

Comment: @Mysticial thanks. I added your first link.